# How can I save changes in .env file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching, config, dotenv

I have a huge problem with .env file in Laravel. When I make a change in .env file, it is not changed. I think all of you know what I'm talking about. I run this `php artisan config:cache`, but yet, nothing changed! I echo out a variable in .env file and nothing changed. What can I do for that?

Comment: you need to run `composer du`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cache the configuration all calls to `env` will return `null` because it does not load the `.env` any more. You should not have any calls to `env` outside of the config files.

You use the configuration system to get the values you want, which is why the config files make calls to `env` to get values from the environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you using `php artisan serve` you have to reload it after changing `.env` file